# Pentest for shellshock via url?

Tags: web-application, penetration-test, shellshock

I have been hit by probes in the past that were delivering a shell shock validation string `x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable'` via a URL / browser based method hitting public facing web services.

What is the best way to approach this kind of validation manually (say during a penetration test)?

Comment: do you mean on web application parameters which accepts the input? If so, are you sure the input parameter does process, parses & actually goes to the *cmd* intake by the residing OS?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your definition of manual, but if I was looking for this on a penetration test, I'd be using Nmap's [http-shellshock](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/http-shellshock.html) script.